# Organic Groups Support for Context Module

Tags: organic-groups, 7

I would like to achieve following functionality.

- In Context Conditions check Group Type such as Pubic, Private, Moderate
- Check User is member of a Group or Not !

Is it possible using any module ?? I verified Context OG module but it's not giving options that i am looking for !

Any solutions to override the context and check for above conditions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read this article? http://drupalconnect.com/blog/creating-drupal-context-plugins

I think it can help you to build you own module to use with context.

Oskar